# TermCollection by language

Tags: 2013, development, taxonomy, term-store

Is it possible to get a TermCollection by a specific language? Something like:

```
TermCollection termcollection = termset.Terms.ByLanguage("de-DE");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace ManagedMetadataClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // ClienContext - Get the context for the SharePoint Site 
            // SharePoint site URL - http://c4968397007/
            ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://c4968397007/");

            // Get the TaxonomySession
            TaxonomySession taxonomySession = TaxonomySession.GetTaxonomySession(clientContext);

            // Get the term store by Name
            TermStore termStore = taxonomySession.TermStores.GetByName("MMS");

            // Get the term group by Name
            TermGroup termGroup = termStore.Groups.GetByName("SP2013");

            // Get the term set by Name
            TermSet termSet = termGroup.TermSets.GetByName("BCS");

            // Get the term by Name 
            Term term = termSet.Terms.GetByName("External Content Type");

            // int variable - LCID
            int lcid = 1033;

            // Get all the labels for English language
            LabelCollection labelColl = term.GetAllLabels(lcid);

            clientContext.Load(labelColl);

            // Execute the query to the server
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            // Loop through all the labels
            foreach (Label label in labelColl)
            {
                // Display the label value
                Console.WriteLine(label.Value);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();   
        }
    }
}
```

[How to get all the term labels for a particular language using Client Side Object Model in SharePoint 2013](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/10869/how-to-get-all-the-term-labels-for-a-particular-language-usi.aspx)